# React Navigation Error (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.router.getStateForAction'))

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

I am Trying to create a simple navigation in React Native. but I keep getting this error that I think is linked to the react Native navigation library.

**Here is my App.js code :**

```
 import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
    import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
    import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
    import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";

    const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

    function MyTabs() {
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );
    }

    export default createAppContainer(MyTabs);
```

**This is the error its generating :**

[image]

Comment: Can i know your navigation library version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two versions of Navigators here, the createAppContainer is used with Navigation version and the createMaterialBottomTabNavigator is used with navigation version 5. If you want to use createMaterialBottomTabNavigator the code should look like below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification ! Its working now that I fixed that